# Israel tourist visa renewal

Tags: visas, regulations, israel, visa-runs, tourist-visas

How long are you supposed to stay out of Israel after your 3 month tourist visa has expired in order to get another tourist visa?

I'm a U.S. citizen, if it matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

US citizens don't need a visa to Israel, and get admitted for up to 3 months (90 days) at a time. Once you left Israel - you can be readmitted for additional 90 days, but leaving through land crossings for several days in Jordan/Egypt might not count as "leaving" (similarly, by the way, as the US treats foreign tourists leaving to Canada/Mexico and then coming back).

If you're leaving  by air and coming back by air then you should be fine, but if the border control suspects that you work/live in Israel (i.e.: you keep leaving for a week or two and then coming back for another 90 days) they might deport you. Once deported - you'll probably have to obtain a visa prior to boarding before coming back next time.

If you're in Israel - you can extend your stay at the population registration offices (they might deny your request, so keep that in mind, especially if they suspect you to be working).

Comment: When you say `might not count as "leaving"` are you making an assumption or do you know this for sure? Because different countries have very different rules. USA insists you go further away than Canada or Mexico. For some countries you have to be gone for say a week or more. For some the wording of the rule is that you can stay for `90 days within any 180 day period`. And for some you can literally get your exit stamp, walk across the border to get your entry stamp and right away another exist stamp then walk right back to get a new entry stamp!

Comment: @hippietrail I don't know for sure, but I'm not making an assumption, I read it on some official site. I cannot find it right now, I'll try to locate it again later. In Israel you can easily extend your stay without leaving the country, walking out and then walking right back in may leave you in an unpleasant situation if your entry is denied.

Comment: @littleadv: If you can find the official site I will be all in favour of this answer. I tried the walk out and walk back in trick in Mexico at the Guatemala border once and it didn't work. So I just told my friend who came with me to the border that I'd see him in a week or two (-: Nothing ventured nothing gained. But I know the situation at Israel's borders might sometimes be a bit different...

Comment: @hippietrail even if there's no official rule, nothing ensures it cannot happen. They have the right to refuse entry, and they don't have to explain. You can of course do that, but you need to make sure you know what to do if you're refused to return, regardless of whether there's an official rule to refuse all such cases, or its the judgment of the officer at the border. That's true everywhere.

Comment: True indeed but a "maybe yes maybe no" answer doesn't leave the OP's original question of "how long" any closer to an answer. But of course all your other objective info about extending your stay is good stuff (-:

Comment: In 1998-2000 (I realize this is quite old), leaving Israel for Jordan or Egypt *except Sinai* reset the tourist visa clock. The clock did not reset going just to the Sinai, via the Taba land crossing, which then (and now according to Egypt web site) could be done with a special permit obtained at the border and not a regular visa. (Personal experience.)

Answer (score 7):

Based on the [Israel's MFA website](http://www.mfa.gov.il/MFA/About+the+Ministry/Consular_affairs/Visas.htm#B/2)

> A B/2 visa is valid for up to three months from the date of issue. The duration of the stay in Israel will be determined by the Border Police. A visitor who wishes to extend his visit may submit an application at one of the regional population administration offices of the Ministry of the Interior.

So just follow the instructions listed on the page and you should be good.