# How long am I supposed to stay out of Israel after 3 months tourist visa has expired

Tags: visas, regulations, israel, visa-runs

I am EU citizen (Greece). I was in Israel 2 weeks ago and I stayed around 3 months. I left 3 days before my tourist visa expired. How long am I supposed to stay out of Israel after 3 months tourist visa has expired in order to get another tourist visa?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6047/israel-tourist-visa-renewal

Answer (score 3):

Israel does not seem to require a tourist to stay out of Israel for a certain period before requesting another visa. None of their [visa information pages](http://www.goisrael.com/Tourism_Eng/Tourist%20Information/Planning%20your%20trip/Pages/Visa.aspx) mention it.

[This](http://www.tau.ac.il/visitors/visas.html) page mentions that you will be able to renew your tourist visa for up to a year and then annually by contacting the Ministry of Interior. [Here](http://igoogledisrael.com/2008/10/israel-visa-requirements/) is a list of offices of the Ministry of Interior.

Theoretically, you could just leave briefly (ex. hop over to Jordan and back) and get a new visa on entry an unlimited number of times, but this could raise suspicions that you are doing business in Israel, and you are strictly prohibited from working on a tourist visa.

Comment: Some countries just don't really make known the rule about how long you need to stay out. I came up against this in Mexico once years ago.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there's no time requirement.  You simply have to exit the country and then re-enter, and you'll get a new tourist visa.

You do need to be careful, as if you do that enough times they'll start to get mad, since you're not supposed to abuse it to get an de facto residency visa.  That being said, you can.